# Android Google Map app directly jump to specific location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using the below code to open the google maps app and redirect the user to a specific position.

```
@Override
public void openMap(EService service) {
    if (service != null && UString.stringsExist(service.latitude, service.longitude, service.address)) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                "geo:<" + service.latitude + ">,<" + service.longitude + ">?q=<" + service.latitude + ">,<" + service.longitude + ">(" + service.address + ")")
        );

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_no_application_found_for_action), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that when the app opens it first jumps to my current location and after a second it moves to the location I gave it. Is there a way to DIRECTLY move to the location I specify?

**EDIT**

I'm on an S3 running 4.3.

Comment: What happens if you turn off location service in mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding "<" and ">" as separators for the latitude/longitude ?

According to the documentation, the correct way to do what you want is :

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:"+ service.latitude +","+ service.latitude +"?q="+ service.latitude + "," + service.longitude + "(" + service.address + ")");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: Nope .. that doesn't work either ... I thought it did for a sec, but no ... :(

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour if you don't make the query (removing all the stuff starting with `?q=`) ?

Comment: No, removing everything after `?q=` makes it not jump to any location ... at all. It does indeed have a marker places on top of the coords, but it doesn't make the camera move to that location. It doesn't zoom on ...